# Not able to fetch Impala hive external table data (ERROR: NullPointerException: null)

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase, impala

I have created `hbase` table example(employee_hbase table) into `HBASE`.Using `csv` file imported data into hbase table successfully.

Then I have used employee_hbase table data into hive using external table command.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE employee (txtno int,ymd string,custno int,amount float,category string,product string,city string,state string,spentby string)
    STORED BY \'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler\'
    WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key,details:empno,details:salary,details:city,details:state,details:emp_name")
    TBLPROPERTIES ("hbase.table.name" = "employee_hbase"
```

I am able to see all the data of employee table `hive`. I want real time data so I want data into impala.

In impala shell First I have used following command for showing tables into impala.

```
[c6401.ambari.apache.org:21000] > invalidate metadata;
```

After that I am able to see employee table into impala but when I am trying to fetch data query then getting following error.

```
[c6401.ambari.apache.org:21000] > select * from transactions;
Query: select * from transactions
Query submitted at: 2017-05-25 12:27:03 (Coordinator: http://c6401.ambari.apache.org:25000)
ERROR: NullPointerException: null
```

I have also try with refresh command but not getting data.

Comment: Did you check the Impala documentation for what kind of "storage" it supports?? That's a rhetorical question, because it's clear that you didn't.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter Do you mean I can not fetch real time data from impala !!!

Comment: The point is not "real time" _(whatever that means)_, it's "HBase vs. Impala". To run fast SQL queries on HBase back-end, you can try Apache Phoenix. To run SQL queries with Impala on a back-end that accepts row-level updates, try Apache Kudu. https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/impala_file_formats.html

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter Thanks for you answer but I am using php and I am not sure about Phoenix support php or not. let me check and let me know your concerns regarding Phoenix with php.

Comment: Actually I was mistaken, Impala is supposed to work "out of the box" with HBase -- at least in CDH distro, cf. https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/impala_hbase.html >> but be aware that HBase is HBase is HBase, placating a query engine on top of it will not magically allow "real time" SQL queries, you would need an indexing layer...